# Ruby - How to sum values of a hash based on a given date (=key)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, hash

I have these values in a hash:

```
{nil=>0, 
Thu, 03 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381db8,'0.151875E2',18(27)>, 
Fri, 04 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381cf0,'0.214375E2',18(27)>, 
Wed, 09 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381c28,'0.6229E2',18(27)>, 
Thu, 10 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381b60,'0.1243E2',18(27)>, 
Fri, 11 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381a98,'0.1243E2',18(27)>, 
Mon, 14 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963819d0,'0.6611E2',18(27)>, 
Tue, 15 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381908,'0.625E1',18(18)>, 
Wed, 16 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381840,'0.73345E2',18(27)>, 
Thu, 17 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381778,'0.31845E2',18(27)>, 
Fri, 18 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963816b0,'0.409225E2',18(27)>, 
Mon, 21 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963815e8,'0.8019E2',18(27)>, 
Mon, 28 Dec 2015=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381520,'0.3125E2',18(27)>, 
Mon, 04 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381458,'0.125E2',18(27)>, 
Wed, 06 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381390,'0.625E2',18(27)>, 
Thu, 07 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963812c8,'0.9111E2',18(27)>, 
Fri, 08 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963811d8,'0.11972E3',18(27)>, 
Mon, 11 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963810e8,'0.5022E2',18(27)>, 
Wed, 13 Jan 2016=>0, Thu, 14 Jan 2016=>0, Fri, 15 Jan 2016=>0, 
Wed, 09 Mar 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496380eb8,'0.258125E2',18(27)>, 
Tue, 15 Mar 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496380da0,'0.631825E2',18(27)>, 
Wed, 16 Mar 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496380cd8,'0.504225E2',18(27)>, 
Thu, 17 Mar 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496380c10,'0.125E2',18(27)>, 
Fri, 18 Mar 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496380b48,'0.631825E2',18(27)>, 
Mon, 21 Mar 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496380a80,'0.167925E2',18(27)>, 
Tue, 22 Mar 2016=>0}
```

I am looping through some calendar data (`@dates`) and from here I get two variables containing a specific year and month:

```
@dates.each do |d|
    current_yer   = d.strftime('%Y') #2016
    current_month = d.strftime('%m') # 01 - january
```

Now, I have variables containing the dates, I would like to print out a sum of all data in the hash; so in this case, I would like to get something like this as output:

> 2016 01: SUM of all January items in the hash

specifically, SUM of these:

```
Mon, 04 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381458,'0.125E2',18(27)>,

Wed, 06 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff496381390,'0.625E2',18(27)>, 

Thu, 07 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963812c8,'0.9111E2',18(27)>, 

Fri, 08 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963811d8,'0.11972E3',18(27)>, 

Mon, 11 Jan 2016=>#<BigDecimal:7ff4963810e8,'0.5022E2',18(27)>, 

Wed, 13 Jan 2016=>0, Thu, 14 Jan 2016=>0, Fri, 15 Jan 2016=>0,
```

How to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `select` and `sum`:

```
@dates.select{|d, _| d.strftime('%Y %m') == '2016 01'}.values.sum
```

Comment: Note that one of `@dates`' keys is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

**Construct example hash**

First let's construct a hash (`h`) that is similar to yours, but a bit smaller:

```
g = { 
  "Thu, 03 Dec 2015"=> 1,
  "Fri, 11 Dec 2015"=> 2,
  "Mon, 14 Dec 2015"=> 3,
  "Tue, 15 Dec 2015"=> 4,
  "Wed, 16 Dec 2015"=> 5,
  "Fri, 18 Dec 2015"=> 6,
  "Mon, 21 Dec 2015"=> 7,
  "Mon, 04 Jan 2016"=> 8, 
  "Fri, 08 Jan 2016"=> 9, 
  "Wed, 13 Jan 2016"=> 0,
  "Thu, 14 Jan 2016"=> 0,
  "Wed, 09 Mar 2016"=>10, 
  "Tue, 15 Mar 2016"=>11, 
  "Wed, 16 Mar 2016"=>12, 
  "Mon, 21 Mar 2016"=>13, 
  "Tue, 22 Mar 2016"=> 0 }

require 'date'
require 'bigdecimal'

h = { nil=>0 }.tap { |h| g.each { |k,v|
  h[Date.strptime(k, "%a, %d %b %Y")] = v.zero? ? 0 : BigDecimal.new(v) } }
```

```
  #=> {nil=>0,
  #    #<Date: 2015-12-03 ((2457360j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef915c8e0,'0.1E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-12-11 ((2457368j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914ff28,'0.2E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-12-14 ((2457371j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j) >=>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914f938,'0.3E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-12-15 ((2457372j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914f7a8,'0.4E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-12-16 ((2457373j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914f320,'0.5E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-12-18 ((2457375j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914e8d0,'0.6E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2015-12-21 ((2457378j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914dde0,'0.7E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-01-04 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914dca0,'0.8E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-01-08 ((2457396j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914d390,'0.9E1',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-01-13 ((2457401j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      0,
  #    #<Date: 2016-01-14 ((2457402j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      0,
  #    #<Date: 2016-03-09 ((2457457j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef914cd28,'0.1E2',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-03-15 ((2457463j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef913ff60,'0.11E2',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-03-16 ((2457464j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef913f8d0,'0.12E2',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-03-21 ((2457469j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      #<BigDecimal:7faef913f560,'0.13E2',9(27)>,
  #    #<Date: 2016-03-22 ((2457470j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> =>
  #      0
}
```

Here I've used the class methods [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) and [BigDecimal::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new).

**Sum `BigDecimal` values by month**

We can now use [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject), [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) and [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) to obtain the results you require:

```
sums =
h.reject { |k,_| k.nil? }.
  group_by { |k,_| [k.year, k.month] }.
  map { |yr_and_mon, arr| [yr_and_mon, arr.reduce(0) { |t,(_,bd)| t+bd }] }.
  to_h
    #=> {[2015, 12]=>#<BigDecimal:7faef9197eb8,'0.28E2',9(18)>,
    #    [2016,  1]=>#<BigDecimal:7faef9197b70,'0.17E2',9(18)>,
    #    [2016,  3]=>#<BigDecimal:7faef9197760,'0.46E2',9(18)>}
```

We see that the `BigDecimal` values more easily by converting them to integers:

```
sums.merge(sums) { |*,v| v.to_i }
  #=> {[2015, 12]=>28, [2016, 1]=>17, [2016, 3]=>46}
```

Compare these results with the hash `g` at the beginning of this answer.

I used the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. As I am merging `sums` with itself, the block is used to determine the values of all keys.

Once you have the hash `sums` it's an easy task to print the totals by month and year in any format you want.

**The steps**

```
h1 = h.reject { |k,_| k.nil? }.group_by { |k,_| [k.year, k.month] }
  #=> {[2015, 12]=>[[#<Date: 2015-12-03 ((2457360j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #                    #<BigDecimal:7faef915c8e0,'0.1E1',9(27)>],
  #                 [#<Date: 2015-12-11 ((2457368j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #                    #<BigDecimal:7faef914ff28,'0.2E1',9(27)>],
  ...
  #                    #<BigDecimal:7faef9093850,'0.46E2',9(18)>]]
a1 = h1.map { |yr_and_mon, arr| [yr_and_mon, arr.reduce(0) { |t,(_,bd)| t+bd }] }
  #=> [[[2015, 12], #<BigDecimal:7faef9029dd8,'0.28E2',9(18)>],
  #    [[2016,  1], #<BigDecimal:7faef90296a8,'0.17E2',9(18)>],
  #    [[2016,  3], #<BigDecimal:7faef9028dc0,'0.46E2',9(18)>]] 
a1.to_h
  #=> {[2015, 12]=>#<BigDecimal:7faef9098710,'0.28E2',9(18)>,
  #    [2016,  1]=>#<BigDecimal:7faef9093da0,'0.17E2',9(18)>,
  #    [2016,  3]=>#<BigDecimal:7faef9093850,'0.46E2',9(18)>}
```